# Error in iOS7. view controller won't show

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

Having a strange problem that is getting me into a bit of a panic. Just tested my app on iOS7, when I try to present one of my view controller via segue. I get the error message:

```
 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '`**Application tried to present a nil modal view controller on target <SendMessageViewController: 0x15524320>.'**`
```

Have no idea why this is happening. It works fine in iOS8 but could someone give me some pointers to what I might be doing wrong please?

Comment: And please share you're code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all check the identifier of the viewcontroller is same that you mentioned in storyboard.

Than set back point on this exception to see if model is not **nill**.

`UIAlertController` is not supported by iOS 7 so in you're situation you should check the version of the iOS device and that use particular logic.

Use condition to detect if it is possible to use `UIAlertController`

```
if NSClassFromString("UIAlertController") != nil {
    // Use it
} else {
    // Fall back
}
```

Comment: I tried removing all the code from the VIewController to see if it was something inside it and it worked. Not sure what it is that is breaking it though. Can UIAlertController be used in iOS7?

Comment: Hey, I fixed it. It was the UIAlertController that is not supported in ios that caused it to crash. Thanks for your help!